# paginate_links ignore my format

Tags: wp-query, pagination, urls, query-variable

I need the pagination liks to have the url, like:

```
current_url?p-page=1
current_url?p-page=2
current_url?p-page=3
```

And so.. The reason I need this is because I have other params in the page.

the problem is that in the docs, it specs:

**format**

> (string) (optional) Used for Pagination structure. The default value
>   is '?page=%#%', If using pretty permalinks this would be '/page/%#%',
>   where the '%#%' is replaced by the page number. Default: '?page=%#%'

And I have friendly url enabled,

How can I prevent the default ( BTW it ignores my `p-page`, still using `page` )

```
current_url/page/1
current_url/page/2
current_url/page/3
```

this is my code, right now:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'p-page' ) ),
    'format'       => '?p-page=%#%',
    'show_all'     => false,
    'type'         => 'plain',
    'end_size'     => 2,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'prev_next'    => true,
    'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>' ),
    'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>' ),
    'add_args'     => false,
    'add_fragment' => '',
) );
```

As a temporary solution I'm doing it like this:

```
if ($current_page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="?p-page='.($current_page-1).'" class="page-numbers prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>';
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $query->max_num_pages; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="?p-page='.$i.'" class="page-numbers '.($current_page == $i ? 'current' : '').'">'.$i.'</a>';
}
if ($current_page < $query->max_num_pages) {
    echo '<a href="?p-page='.($current_page+1).'" class="page-numbers prev"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>';
}
```

But would be great to take advantage of the dots functionality and so.. any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This part:

```
'base' => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
```

is generating a `page` part like this one:

```
'base' => http://example.tld/page/%#%/
```

If we peek into [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) we see the default:

```
'base' => $pagenum_link, // http://example.com/all_posts.php%_% : 
                         // %_% is replaced by format (below)
'format' => $format,     // ?page=%#% : %#% is replaced by the page number
```

where the inline comment say that `%_%` is replaced by the format.

The documentation also says:

> An example of the `‘base’` argument is
>   `"http://example.com/all_posts.php%_%"` and the `‘%_%’` is required. The
>   `‘%_%’` will be replaced by the contents of in the `‘format’` argument. An
>   example for the `‘format’` argument is `"?page=%#%"` and the ‘%#%’ is also
>   required. The `‘%#%’` will be replaced with the page number.

If we use that:

```
'base' => '%_%'
```

then it will become the same as the `format` argument.

Here's a modification of OP's example:

```
echo paginate_links( 
    [
        'base'         => '%_%',
        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => $current,
        'format'       => '?p-page=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => '<i></i> <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>',
        'next_text'    => '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> <i></i>',
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ]
);
```

where we use:

```
$current   = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'p-page' ) );
```

that will also go into the `WP_Query` argument of `$query`:

```
'paged' => $current,
```

Example output for `?p-page=6` :

```
<a class="prev page-numbers" href="?p-page=5"><i></i> <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class='page-numbers' href=''>1</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?p-page=2'>2</a>
<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?p-page=5'>5</a>
<span class='page-numbers current'>6</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?p-page=7'>7</a>
<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?p-page=99'>99</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?p-page=100'>100</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="?p-page=7"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> <i></i></a>
```

ps: There's no need for `sprintf` to combine two static strings, as we see in the OP for `prev_text` and `next_text`. Currently that part looks wrong in the original snippet, so I removed it.

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: Id did help, thank you so much. Just one last question about the paging, how could i add to every link data-page="{the-page}" ? I'm checking in https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links but cant find a way

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. There are no explicit filters for that, (just the paginate_links filter to modify the href attribute of each a tag) so you might try to play with preg_replace() on the output. For extensive modifications, it might be better to use a custom function, based on paginate_links().